# Problemas ao enviar e-mail com JavaMail

Tags: java, jsf, javamail

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java Web com PrimeFaces no qual uso o javaMail para enviar email com as informações do usuário, mas está dando erro.

O Bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EnvioEmailBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Mailer mailer;

    @Inject
    @EnvioEdicao
    private Usuario usuario;

    public void enviarEmail(){
        MailMessage message = mailer.novaMensagem();

        message.to(this.usuario.getEmail())
        .subject("Informações de acesso ao sistema")
        .bodyHtml("<strong>Login:</strong> "+ this.usuario.getEmail() + 
                " com sua senha: ").send();

        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("E-mail enviado com sucesso!");
    }

}
```

O MailConfiguração

```
public class MailConfigProducer {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public SessionConfig getMailConfig() throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mail.properties"));

        SimpleMailConfig config = new SimpleMailConfig();
        config.setServerHost(props.getProperty("mail.server.host"));
        config.setServerPort(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("mail.server.port")));
        config.setEnableSsl(Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("mail.enable.ssl")));
        config.setAuth(Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("mail.auth")));
        config.setUsername(props.getProperty("mail.username"));
        config.setPassword(props.getProperty("mail.password"));

        return config;
    }

}
```

E por fim...

```
mail.server.host=smtp.gmail.com

mail.server.port=465

mail.enable.ssl=true

mail.auth=true

mail.username=******@gmail.com

mail.password=********
```

O erro que aparecer é.

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{envioEmailBean.enviarEmail}: com.outjected.email.api.SendFailedException: Send Failed
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 53 more

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: com.outjected.email.api.SendFailedException: Send Failed
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 58 more

Caused by: com.outjected.email.api.SendFailedException: Send Failed
    at com.outjected.email.impl.MailMessageImpl.send(MailMessageImpl.java:398)
    at com.outjected.email.impl.MailMessageImpl.send(MailMessageImpl.java:405)
    at com.outjected.email.impl.MailMessageImpl.send(MailMessageImpl.java:409)
    at com.outjected.email.impl.MailMessageImpl.send(MailMessageImpl.java:420)
    at com.odontoclinicas.clinicas.controller.EnvioEmailBean.enviarEmail(EnvioEmailBean.java:33)
    at com.odontoclinicas.clinicas.controller.EnvioEmailBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.enviarEmail(EnvioEmailBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 59 more

Caused by: com.outjected.email.api.SendFailedException: Send Failed
    at com.outjected.email.impl.util.MailUtility.send(MailUtility.java:276)
    at com.outjected.email.impl.MailTransporterImpl.send(MailTransporterImpl.java:35)
    at com.outjected.email.impl.MailMessageImpl.send(MailMessageImpl.java:395)
    ... 74 more

Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.outjected.email.impl.util.MailUtility.send(MailUtility.java:273)
    ... 76 more

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 83 more

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 94 more

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 100 more
```

Comment: Removi as saudaçoes, não é necessário no modelo do site, como pode ser lido aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/28595

Answer (score 1):

Passei por este problema, segui os passos seguintes e funcionou.

1- Siga os passos do site: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en-PT ou verifique se as propriedades estão igual do fonte no fim do comentário.

2- Adicione este properties. Ele foi primordial para o funcionamento do código: **properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com")**

3- Habilite o Google Autenticator. Pegue a chave gerada para colocar no código. O fonte abaixo indica onde colocar a chave gerada. Tutorial de como criar a chave: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=pt

Por fim, o código que implementei:

```
public static void enviaEmail(String destinatario, String assunto, String mensagem) throws Exception{       

        String porta = "465";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com" );
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.from", destinatario );
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", porta);
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", porta);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session sessionEmail = Session.getInstance(props, null);


        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(sessionEmail);
            msg.setFrom(destinatario);
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, "meuemail@gmail.com" );
            msg.setSubject(assunto);
            msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("meuemail@gmail.com", false));
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setContent(mensagem, "text/html");
            Transport.send(msg, "meuemail@gmail.com","***COLOQUEAQUI_A_CHAVE_DO_PASSO_3***");

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            log.error("Erro durante envio de email." + mex);
            throw mex;          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não testei o seu código, mas porta para o smtp do Google usando SSL é a 587, pode ser este o problema com o seu código.

Um exemplo completo de como enviar email usando javax.mail pode ser visto [aqui](http://crunchify.com/java-mailapi-example-send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp/).

### Update:

Esqueci de informar que ao mudar a porta para 587 você deve setar a configuração de SSL para false e a de TSL para true. Você pode conferir um código detalhado no link acima e [nesta resposta do SO EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597616/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-java).

E reparei também que nos nomes das propriedades está faltando o stmp, os nomes corretos deveriam ser assim:

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable -> true
mail.smtp.host -> smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user -> nome de usuário da conta do gmail
mail.smtp.password  -> senha
mail.smtp.port -> 587
mail.smtp.auth -> true
```

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Espero que ajude a resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Quando utiliza o Windows vc precisa desabilitar o firewall e desativar o anti-virus. Obrigado pela força